# Turn html tags into arrays in php

Tags: php, html, arrays

I was wondering if you could turn html tags into an array.

```
   <title>aa</title>
  <link>http://dailynews.yahoo.co.jp/fc/domestic/nuke_disaster_prevention/?id=6170385</link>
    <pubDate>Wed, 12 Aug 2015 17:14:19 +0900</pubDate>
    <guid isPermaLink="false">yahoo/news/topics/6170385</guid>
    </item>
    <item>
    <title>bb</title>
    <link>http://dailynews.yahoo.co.jp/fc/local/okinawa_us_armed_forces/?id=6170398</link>
    <pubDate>Wed, 12 Aug 2015 17:57:37 +0900</pubDate>
    <enclosure length="133" url="http://i.yimg.jp/images/icon/photo.gif" type="image/gif">
    </enclosure>
    <guid isPermaLink="false">yahoo/news/topics/6170398</guid>
    </item>
```

I have these html tags and I want to turn it into arrays by tags( by title, link, description etc)
Is it possible because I want it to be an array so i can insert it into my database's table.

Comment: How do you want your arrays look like? What database engine are you using?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Have you tried something ?

Comment: Array (Title -> aa, link -> hkjhljkhjk, pubDate -> hkjhlkjhj) like this

Comment: Start reading: [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php)

Comment: No, I can't find anything on the web

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your content looks like XML? You could use `simplexml_load_string()` to interpret the XML string into an object:

```
<?php
$mytext ='
<items>

    <item>
        <title>aa</title>
        <link>http://dailynews.yahoo.co.jp/fc/domestic/nuke_disaster_prevention/?id=6170385</link>
        <pubDate>Wed, 12 Aug 2015 17:14:19 +0900</pubDate>
        <guid isPermaLink="false">yahoo/news/topics/6170385</guid>
    </item>

    <item>
        <title>bb</title>
        <link>http://dailynews.yahoo.co.jp/fc/local/okinawa_us_armed_forces/?id=6170398</link>
        <pubDate>Wed, 12 Aug 2015 17:57:37 +0900</pubDate>
        <enclosure length="133" url="http://i.yimg.jp/images/icon/photo.gif" type="image/gif">
        </enclosure>
        <guid isPermaLink="false">yahoo/news/topics/6170398</guid>
    </item>

</items>';

$xml = simplexml_load_string($mytext);
print_r($xml);
 ?>
```

**Output**:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [item] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [title] => aa
                    [link] => http://dailynews.yahoo.co.jp/fc/domestic/nuke_disaster_prevention/?id=6170385
                    [pubDate] => Wed, 12 Aug 2015 17:14:19 +0900
                    [guid] => yahoo/news/topics/6170385
                )

            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [title] => bb
                    [link] => http://dailynews.yahoo.co.jp/fc/local/okinawa_us_armed_forces/?id=6170398
                    [pubDate] => Wed, 12 Aug 2015 17:57:37 +0900
                    [enclosure] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [length] => 133
                                    [url] => http://i.yimg.jp/images/icon/photo.gif
                                    [type] => image/gif
                                )

                        )

                    [guid] => yahoo/news/topics/6170398
                )

        )

)
```

**Loop through the object and insert the values to the database**

```
foreach($xml as $item) {

    //Insert into database
    echo $item->title;
    echo $item->link;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it by using the following example. then convert string to array

```
<?php
 $myhtml = <<<EOF
 ?>
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>My Page</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <p><a href="/mypage1">Hello World!</a></p>
 <p><a href="/mypage2">Another Hello World!</a></p>
 </body>
 </html><?php
 EOF;

 $doc = new DOMDocument();
 $doc->loadHTML($myhtml);

 $tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a');

 foreach ($tags as $tag) {
   echo $tag->getAttribute('href').' | '.$tag->nodeValue."\n";
 }

 ?>
```